# Moving from local asset folders to Google Cloud, Amazon, etc

Tags: assets

I've setup a few clients with Google's Cloud storage recently and am thinking of offering it to other clients with image-intensive sites, as a kind of retro-fit.

One option will be to just create new asset folders and start using those instead of the current asset folders, but I'm also wondering if anyone has any experience of switching existing assets from local folders to Google Cloud (or Amazon, etc) and how much work was involved?

Thanks,
Clive

Comment: Clive, does this answer your question: [Is it possible to move an entire asset source?](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1212/125)

Comment: Could well be. I see no reason that would work the other way. I'll try it on a dev site.