# Can you store cropped cloud assets locally?

Tags: assets, cache

Currently I'm seeing them cropped and stored on the remote bucket.

Is there a way to force them to be stored locally and retrievable via an Asset URL method?

Comment: What do you mean with cropped? Craft transforms? And you now want to store the whole file structure locally?

Comment: Does this help: [Is it possible to move an entire asset source?](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1212/125)?

Comment: Yes sorry - Transforms. So the remote source holds the original file but the local cache dir holds the result of the transform.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why not just use a local source then?

Comment: It is a strange requirement, admittedly. This particular use case is for one remote source used by more than 1 site. But the client wants to have 'processed' assets stored (i.e. source controlled) locally. Edge case....