# Bulk moving asset folders, from one source to another

Tags: assets, migration, sources

I'm moving all of my assets from a local folder to Amazon S3. I've got my S3 source all set up, and I've been migrating folders over to it by dragging & dropping.

The problem is, I have **thousands** of asset folders. I did the math, and it'll take me 4+ hours to drag & drop each of them.

**Is there some way to bulk move asset folders?**

If it's not possible in the CP, I'm open to plugin suggestions as well.

Comment: I discovered the **right** answer way too late... For future reference, [this is the right way to do it...](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/is-it-possible-to-move-an-entire-asset-source/1215#1215)

Comment: Bookmark and use the information in this link:

http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/is-it-possible-to-move-an-entire-asset-source/1215

Answer (score 1):

I did this with [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), using the [grunt-aws-s3](https://github.com/MathieuLoutre/grunt-aws-s3) task. It worked beautifully. If you are a [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) person, I'm sure there is something similar for gulp.

Comment: Interesting... and that maintained all of the asset relationships? Or did you have to reindex your assets?

Comment: I may have reindexed afterwards. But it got rid of the tedium of moving them.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's gonna work for me. I'm not bothered by physically moving them. I need to maintain the existing relationships between these assets and thousands of entries.

Comment: Maybe you can move them by just uploading all assets to S3 manually. Then in the database go in and change the "Asset ID" for the current selection of assets to your new "S3 Asset folder". Since the paths are the same... this might work.

Comment: @naboovalley Very interesting! I'll test that out and let you know if it does the trick. Would you mind submitting that as a separate answer?

Comment: @naboovalley Disregard my previous comment... I ended up going a different route.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this the old-fashioned way... **hire cheap labor to do a tedious repetitious task!**

Every other suggestion I got (here and in Slack) involved command line scripting and/or careful database manipulation. I wasn't really comfortable with either of those, especially since I had already started the drag & drop process.

So in the end, I just hired one of my buddies (for dirt cheap) to manually drag & drop each folder to the new source. Problem solved! :)

Comment: Despite the fact that this actually solved my problem, I won't officially mark it as the correct answer. It's certainly atypical for a programmer to solve a problem this way, and it won't necessarily be the best solution for other folks who discover this thread.